# How to restore xterm colors after quitting emacs

Tags: emacs, xterm

When I use emacs from a terminal (xterm-color; a putty ssh session in this case) the font color used by emacs is different from the one I use in the shell. Which is fine. BUT, after I quit emacs (or suspend it for that matter) the colors are not restored.

*Is there anything I can do to restore my term colors when returning to the shell after my emacs session?*

I have aliased my *ls* command to add *--color* option, which if I run it restores my colors if the listing shows any files with "non-default" color, but that is a rather ugly way to get my colors back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a wrapper script for emacs that runs "tput reset" after emacs exits:

```
#!/bin/sh
emacs &
pid=$!
wait $pid
trap "kill $pid 2>/dev/null; tput reset" TERM INT EXIT
```

Comment: Thanks!
This got me started. I had to modify it slightly, since my "emacs" was in turn a wrapper script to run another binary.

Comment: where does one type in this wrapper script? emacs or unix terminal?

Comment: Erik: That's a shell script that you would most likely add to `~/bin/` (provided it has precedence in your `$PATH` environment variable). You will also need to use `chmod` to make sure the script is executable.